# Htaccess contents keep getting replaced on shared hosting

Tags: .htaccess

The content in my shared hosting htaccess file keeps getting replaced with this:

```
<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(about.php|radio.php|index.php|content.php|lock360.php|admin.php|wp-login.php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried location the script causing this but could not find it. I asked my hosting service and they claim it not caused by them.
Please do anyone have idea to what's causing this

Comment: This a WordPress system? Then why does your .htaccess not contain the `BEGIN WordPress`/ `END WordPress` comments it should? https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/#basic-wp When permalinks get flushed, WordPress itself will _overwrite_ the content between those. If they are missing, it might just replace the whole file content. And the FilesMatch stuff could perhaps come from some security plugin, I suppose.

Comment: I think your site is hacked, check your index file or find in your folder the file lock360.php or contact your provider

Comment: It could be possible that the malicious software is in your cPanel...

Comment: try this service, it could be help you detect the problem: https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/

Comment: [here](https://blog.sucuri.net/2021/12/php-re-infectors-the-malware-that-keeps-on-giving.html) you can find the description of the attack and what to do